# Debian Packagemanager won't install vagrant.deb package on alpine-linux, while building docker image

Tags: ruby, docker, vagrant, dpkg, alpine-linux

I am new to docker but managed to build myself some dev-environment images ( which is awesome! ). But i wasn't quite satisfied with the filesize of the resulting image, so i tried to migrate the image from node-argon image ( based on debian-wheezy ) to alpine image. Problem is that the installation of vagrant.deb package isn't working correctly. I installed the alpine dpkg package, but get these errors:

```
dpkg: error: failed to open package info file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' for reading: No such file or directory
```

I found some threats about this topic, but were not related to alpine installation and wouldn't fix my issues. Relevant docker lines are:

```
FROM gliderlabs/alpine:3.3
RUN apk add --update dpkg
ENV VAGRANT_VERSION 1.8.1
ADD https://releases.hashicorp.com/vagrant/${VAGRANT_VERSION}/vagrant_${VAGRANT_VERSION}_x86_64.deb .
RUN dpkg -i vagrant_${VAGRANT_VERSION}_x86_64.deb
RUN rm vagrant_*.deb
```

Someone else got this working - my guess was that there maybe some build/install dependencies missing, but couldn't get it any further. Any advice would be much appriciated.

All the best, florian

Comment: What a surprise! Debian commands does not work on Alpine!

Comment: Aehm... sry? thx for calling me stupid, but i was asking this seriously... because why would there be a alpine-linux package for debian linux package-manager, if this isn't working at all? - pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/main/x86/dpkg And i couldn't find a vagrant package for other distros debian. Pretty new to docker/ building linux images and did imagine the systems should be similar enough to share software... i am sorry if i was mistaken on this. So you are saying i can't use vagrant on alpine linux - or is there a way to compile it from source or similar?

Comment: I see the `dpkg` command is, for whatever reason available for installation on Alpine. However, Alpine is not a dpkg based distribution. It's - really(!!!) - a hack to integrate that. I could successfully install vagrant on `Alpine` using this [Dockerfile](http://pastebin.com/uKzqJtRE). However, you'll end up with: `bash: /opt/vagrant/embedded/bin/ruby: No such file or directory` ...

Comment: This is because ruby is missing shared library dependencies. I stopped to resolve them when it came to `libcrypt.so`. This little thingy is usually part of the libc. However, Alpine ships with a small libc which seems not ship that library. At the end the question is, why would you install Vagrant in a Docker image?

Comment: One thing, you can use the distro's ruby instead of the embedded one. This fixes the lib dependency problems: `apk add --update ruby; ln -sf /usr/bin/ruby /opt/vagrant/embedded/bin/ruby` ... Now you only need to fix gem dependencies which should be doable.

Comment: Thanks, for your answer ( Even if my comment was rude... ) My use-case is, that i want to virtualize my development-environment, some nodejs global-dep. and the hashicorp-software needed to run otto ( which also depends on vagrant, terraform ) to allow sharing the image across-plattforms ( linux, mac, win ) and having the exact same dependency versions. When i tried otto windows versions didn't work at all, so i thought i give docker a try - maybe it's still stupid to run otto inside a vm? But that was the general idea. i will try your suggestions asap - and comment back.

Comment: Ok. Just a thought, a minimal Debian/Ubuntu image would be far less hackish. You can simply `apt-get install vagrant`, that's it!.

Comment: Take this one for example: https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu/ It's just 188MB large. 246.1 MB  with vagrant

Comment: @hek2mgl Hi again! Run into some more problems - which i am sure are caused by my low experience with using linux/docker in general. But i got my image working using node:argon image - not a 100% satisfied with the size of it ( as it already weights ~2.8 GB with node-globals and hashicorp-software ). But decided it's good enough for a first experiment. I find a merge of your comments 2-3-4 would be an accaptable answer - as it nearly did the trick for me. Would like to give you the points for helping me out. all the best

Comment: Sure, I can do that. However, why don't you use https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu/? It makes things far easier.

Comment: For now mostly because of a lack of time. I tried it once, but wasn't able to install n ( nodejs version manager ) without npm, because the image was also lacking sudo-command. - So i gave up tyring to optimize the image for filesize only, as the big image works and is for my personal use. But i am planing to schedule some more time to dive deeper into docker/linux in the near future. Again thx for your time and help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In comments below the question we found out, that it is indeed possible to install the vagrant.deb using dpkg on Alpine Linux. However, it was really hackish(!) and at the end the advantage in size of the Alpine Linux didn't matter since the resulting image had a size of 2.5G =).

That's why my answer is (I said that before): Make your life easy and use a Debian or Ubuntu image if you want to install deb packages :)

For all potential Alpine-container users, please think twice if you really need a base image that is a couple of MB smaller than common GNU/Linux base images. You'll pay the price for that few MBs with having a poor shell environment (Welcome to the 80s!) and a significantly smaller amount of available packages.

If you want a minimal container then don't put a distribution into a container, put a process into a container!